# Possible moves on a chess board, using instance from one class in another.

Tags: ruby

I'm working on making a chess game. I want to keep everything that has to do with possible moves inside each type of pieces class. In order to do this I need to refer back to @board[][]. The commented section of code in the possible_moves method is what I would like to do, except it does not work and throws an error.

```
class Board 
  attr_accessor :board, :choice
  def initialize
    @board = Array.new(8){Array.new(8," ")}
    @choice = choice 
  end 

  def set_board
    @board[0][2] = Bishop.new([0,2],false) 
  end 
end 

class Bishop
  attr_accessor :x_position, :y_position, :piece, :color, :moves
  def initialize(position,is_white) 
    @x_position = position[0]
    @y_position = position[1]
    @piece = is_white ? "♝" : "♗"
    @color = is_white ? "white" : "black"
    @moves = [[+1,-1],
              [+1,+1],
              [-1,+1],
              [-1,-1]]
  end 

def possible_moves
  move_list = Array.new
  @moves.each do |moves|
    x = @x_position
    y = @y_position
    loop do  
      x += moves[0]
      y += moves[1]
      break if x.between?(0,7) == false 
      break if y.between?(0,7) == false
    # This is where I want to refer back to @board from the Board    class.
    # if @board[x][y].color..... 
        move_list << [x,y] 
      #end 
    end
  end 
  p move_list
end 


end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the board into the Bishop constructor:

```
class Bishop
  attr_reader :board
  # etc.
  def initialize(position,is_white,board) 
    @board = board.board # or just @board = board and you can fetch the matrix later
    # etc.
  end
end

class Board
  # etc.
  def set_board
    @board[0][2] = Bishop.new([0,2],false, self) 
  end 
end
```

Comment: Depresses me I couldn't figure this out. Part of learning I guess.